# What is the fastest way, in Perl, to access a 1.6 millon row list of key/value pairs?

Tags: database, perl, bigdata, performance-testing

I have a list of 1.6 millon lines that looks like this:

```
N123HN  /var/foo/bar/baz/A/Alpha.file.1234.bin
N123HN  /var/foo/bar/baz/A/Alpha.file.1235.bin
N123KL  /var/foo/bar/baz/A/Alpha.file.1236.bin
```

I have a Perl script that basically just greps this data on the second column, as a way of looking up the value in the first column (then it does other magic with the "N123HN" value, etc.). As it is now, my app spends about 4 minutes ingesting the file and loading it into a huge hash (key/value array). While the grep-like functions themselves are slow for obvious reasons, the slowest part of running this script is this huge ingest of data each time it runs.

Anyone have any clever ideas how to access this data more quickly? Since it is just a list of two columns, a relational database seems pretty heavyweight for this use case.

I'm re-editing the original question here since pasting source code into the comments boxes is pretty ugly.

The algorithm I'm using to ingest the huge file is this:

```
while(<HUGEFILE>)
    {
      # hugefile format:
      # nln N123HN ---- 1 0 1c44f5.4a6ee12 17671854355 /var/foo/bar/baz/A/Alpha.file.1234.bin 0

      next if /^(\s)*$/;      # skip blank lines
      chomp;                  # remove trailing newline characters
      @auditrows = split;     # an array of entire rows, split on whitespace
      my $file_url = $auditrows[7];              # /var/foo/bar/baz/A/Alpha.file.1234.bin 
      my $tapenum  = "$auditrows[1] ";          # N123HN
      $tapenumbers{ $file_url } = $tapenum;      # key   = "/var/foo/bar/baz/A/Alpha.file.1234.bin" 
    }                                           # value = "N123HN"
```

Comment: Since somebody will probably ask, what I'm doing with the grep-like function is that I typically have a list of 200 - 400 file paths, which I need to find in the larger file. I'm essentially doing a lookup to find the "N123HN" type value.

Comment: Is the file content changing over time? Otherwise you could just serialize the hash and reload it if necessary.

Comment: You don't need a full fledged database, sqlite3 will work just fine and will index the data.  If you need it as a hash, also good is http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen.html, which will bind the hash to a very fast key-value dbm file.

Comment: The data does change over time, but maybe only every two weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a hash with the second column as the key and the first column as the value?  Then you can iterate over the 200 or so file paths and look them up in the hash directly.  This is probably going to be a lot faster than using the `grep` function.  Here's a  quick script that would load the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %data;
open(my $fh, 'data') || die;
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($k, $path) = split;
    push @{$data{$path}}, $k;
}
print "loaded data: ", scalar(%data), "\n";
```

My perl is pretty rusty, but this runs really quick on my laptop with a 1.6 million line input file.

```
pa-mac-w80475xjagw% head -5 data
N274YQ  /var/foo/bar/baz/GODEBSVT/Alpha.file.9824.bin
N602IX  /var/foo/bar/baz/UISACEXK/Alpha.file.5675.bin
N116CH  /var/foo/bar/baz/GKUQAYWF/Alpha.file.7146.bin
N620AK  /var/foo/bar/baz/DHYRCLUD/Alpha.file.2130.bin
N716YD  /var/foo/bar/baz/NYMSJLHU/Alpha.file.2343.bin
pa-mac-w80475xjagw% wc -l data
 1600000 data
pa-mac-w80475xjagw% /usr/bin/time -l ./parse.pl
loaded data: 1118898/2097152
        5.54 real         5.18 user         0.36 sys
 488919040  maximum resident set size
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
    119627  page reclaims
         1  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
         0  voluntary context switches
        30  involuntary context switches
```

Comment: This is in fact exactly what I'm doing. Or very close:

Comment: Took me a minute, but now I see what you're saying that is different from what I'm doing. You said, "Have you tried using a hash with the second column as the key and the first column as the value? Then you can iterate over the 200 or so file paths and look them up in the hash directly." I'm doing something similar. But my mistake is that instead of doing a lookup into that big hash, I'm iterating through the whole thing, once per 200 or however many file paths I'm searching for. That's about 320 Million string comparisons. oops.

Comment: @LukeSheppard - oh my ... yes.  That would perform very poorly indeed.  The hash lookup should be somewhere on the order of 25 compares for each lookup instead of 0.8 million (avg).

Answer (score 8):

4 minutes?!?! It takes 7 seconds!!!

```
$ perl -E'say "N${_}HN  /var/foo/bar/baz/A/Alpha.file.$_.bin" for 1..1_600_000;' >file

$ time perl -E'my %h; while (<>) { my ($v,$k) = split; $h{$k}=$v; }' file

real    0m7.620s
user    0m7.081s
sys     0m0.249s
```

Maybe you don't have enough memory and it's leading to swapping?

Comment: My first thought was that he was using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, Could be. `for (<>)` would be bad idea since it needlessly loads the entire file into memory. Though that would only double the total memory usage, which should still be fine.

Comment: Uh. Ya. Turns out that for this portion of the program, the "grepish" portion, I'm doing a foreach(@filepaths_to_search_for), then I'm doing a for loop inside of that: for my $key (keys %hugehash). Then, inside of that inner for loop I just do this: if ($string_I_want eq $key). I hope that makes sense. So do you think that is adding to this being slow?

Comment: @Like Sheppard, Are you asking a new question? This is completely unrelated to the question you asked. And really, this isn't the place to ask a new question. The lack of space makes for incomplete and/or unreadable questions (such as that you just asked).